# Whats wrong with fread in this program?

Tags: c, file-io, compiler-errors, fread

I'm intermediate student of C. I'm trying to make a bank management program but first I need to make a login program, so I created one of the following. As I've recently learned about file I/O in C and don't know much about fread and fwrite. I have a file (data.txt) which format if as following.

user1   1124

user2   3215

user3   5431

In the following program I've asked user to input user name and pin(4-digit password) and copy file data into a structure then compare these two for verifying information.

What is wrong with my program and how to make fread work properly. And is the formating in data.txt file all right or should I change it.

Thanks in advance...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

struct user_account    {
    char u_name[30];
    int u_pin;
} log_in;



    int login()
{
    int start;
    int i, n;
    int t_pin[4];       // TEMPORARY INT PIN for storing pin inputed by user
    char t_name[30];    //  TEMPORARY STRING for storing name inputed by user

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("data.txt","rb");        // Opening record file

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
    puts("Unable to open file!");
    return 1;
    }

    start :  {
        printf("User Name : ");
        scanf("%s",&t_name);
        printf("Pin Code  : ");

        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)  {       // This loop is for hiding input pin
            n = getch();

            if(isdigit(n))  {
                t_pin[i] = n;
                printf("*");    }
            else    {
                printf("\b");
                i--;
            }
        }

        fread(&log_in,sizeof(log_in),1,fp);

        // Comparing user name and pin with info in the structure copied from the file

        if(strcmp(log_in.u_name, t_name) == 0 && log_in.u_pin == t_pin)
            puts("Login successful! Welcome User");
        else    {
            printf("\nIncorrect Information!\n");
            printf("Press any key to log in again...");
            getch();
            system("cls");
            goto start; }
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
    int login();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You need to provide a bit more information. What's the issue? Is your code not compiling? If so, provide the compiler error. Is it compiling but not doing what you want it to do? If so, then tell us what you want it to do and what it is doing instead.

Comment: Well I want it to copy that data of file into structure and the I want to compare user name and pin provided by user with structure. If it matches with any of the user in structure. It will go forward or else give user another try. But when I run this program it returns 1 with blank screen nothing shows up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have an ASCII/text file but you are trying to use `fread` to read directly into a structure; this requires a binary formatted file. `fread` cannot do format conversion. Use `fscanf` instead:

```
fscanf(fp, "%s %d", &log_in.u_name, &log_in.u_pin);
```

Comment: Thanks! Which file is the best for fread (binary file) and in which format should I write the data in that file. How should I scan second and third line in file using fscanf. And how does I scan if I've n lines in file and I want to compare user name and pin with whole file.

Comment: To write a binary file compatible with your `fread`, you'd basically need to populate the struct and then `fwrite` it. `fread`/`fwrite` does nothing except transfer the specified number of bytes between the file and memory, with no transformation. Also, note that this is problematic if you are transferring the file between two different endian machines (Google for "endian").

Answer (score 1):

Problems that I see:

1. The following line is incorrect.

   ```
   scanf("%s",&t_name);
   ```

   You need to use:

   ```
   scanf("%29s",t_name);
   ```
2. `fread` is not the right solution given the file format. `fread` works when the file is in binary format.

   Given the format of your input file, you need to use:

   ```
    scanf("%29s %d", log_in.uname, &log_in.u_pin);
   ```
3. Comparing the pins using `log_in.u_pin == t_pin` should produce a compiler error. The type of `log_in.u_pin` is `int` while the type of `t_pin` is `int [4]`. You will have to change your strategy for getting the integer value from `t_pin`.

   You can use something like:

   ```
   int pin = 0; 
   for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
   {
      pin = 10*pin + t_pin[i];
   }
   ```

   However, for that to work, you have store the proper integer values in `t_pin`. When the character you read is `'1'`, you have to store `1`. Either that, or you will have to change the above for loop to:

   ```
      pin = 10*pin + t_pin[i]-'0';
   ```
4. The way are using `goto start` to loop in your function is not correct. You haven't read all the user ID and pins to from the input file and compared them. The way you have it, you will end up doing:

   - Read the user name and pin
   - Check against the first entry in the file. If they don't match...
   - Read the user name and pin again.
   - Check against the next entry in the file. If they don't match...

   etc.

   You want to:

   - Read the user name and pin
   - Check against the first entry in the file. If they don't match...
   - Check against the next entry in the file. If they don't match...
   - Check against the next entry in the file. If they don't match...

   etc.

Comment: With `char u_name[30];`, should use `scanf("%29s%d", log_in.uname, &log_in.u_pin);`.  `"29"` is th maximum width of `char` to scan into in `log_in.uname`.  Then a `'\0'` is appended in `log_in.uname`.  +1 for best answer.

Comment: Is it `scanf("%29s%d", &log_in.u_name, &log_in.u_pin);` ? or `scanf("%29s%d", log_in.uname, &log_in.u_pin);`

Comment: @MirwiseKhan, it's the latter.

Answer (score 0):

a) fread is used to read fixed sized (in bytes) records.  While that is an option, you might find that fscanf is more suited to your use case.

b) goto has its uses, arguably, but in your particular case a while loop is far more appropriate as it make the intention clearer and is less susceptible to misuse.

c) The crux of your issue is reading the file.  You only read in and check against a single record from your file per pass and once all records are read you will be getting EOF rather than additional records.

You have a few options. You might read the entire user table into a list prior to your login loop.  When a user logs in you must iterate through the list until a match or end of list is found. Alternatively you might loop through the entire file on each user attempt looking for a match and seek to the back to the beginning of the file when you are done.  In either case you must check for and handle read errors.

d) Finally when a non-digit is entered you will probably find that backspace isn't what you had in mind.  Also you might consider allowing the user to press backspace while entering the pin.

Comment: Thanks! Can you provide a prototype of log_in loop using fscanf? in that loop how should I tell fscanf to jump to another line and see if the user name & pin matches that record. Finally, please provide me prototype of pin coding as you have mentioned in your answer point (d).